# Magento unsecure_base_url randomly resets to default

Tags: magento, default, reset, base-url

I've been working on a Magento site for a few months now.  About 2 weeks ago, the site suddenly seemed broken.  All the css was gone and I was unable to log into the admin (which was also missing its styles).

I was able to access the database through my host's control panel & found that the unsecure_base_url and secure_base_url were both changed.  I had set them to:

mysubdir.mysite.com/

but now they had /magento on the end like this:

mysubdir.mysite.com/magento/

This was the default value upon installation.  But since the entire site is in magento, I took it out of this directory and moved it into the web root when I started the project.

I manually changed the values in the database, along with my admin password, which was also not working. About a week later, the same thing happened again.  Then a couple days later, it happened again.  Then it happened again in the next day and again in the same day after I fixed it.

In the meantime, I've been scouring the server looking for any scripts that could be running that would change these values.  I haven't found anything.  I looked at every file that had a date matching the time this started & verified with my host that they were legitimate files.

I've also been looking through the magento code, looking for every instance of "core_config_data" to see if I can find any code that sets that value but I haven't found anything yet.

I'm using the community edition.  Is there some code in there that resets the base urls after a trial period or something?  I've searched but can't find anyone else who's experienced this problem.

I did find some magento cache files that contained mysubdir.mysite.com/magento/.  Could it be that it's reverting to cached values?  I've flushed the magento cache and cache storage.  caching is actually disabled on the site at the moment anyway because it's still in development but it was enabled previously.

Thanks in advance for ANY help, leads, or advice.

Answer (score 0):

If it's being set programmatically via some kind of observer or Magento-configured cron, this is the most probable syntax:

```
$config->saveConfig('web/unsecure/base_url', 'http://www.example.com/', 'default');
$config->saveConfig('web/secure/base_url', 'https://www.example.com/', 'default');
```

Knowing this, I'd do a search for this string:

```
grep -Ri "saveConfig('web/secure/base_url" .
grep -Ri "saveConfig('web/unsecure/base_url" .
```

I'd start in app/code, and if that turns up nothing, I'd sit through a grep in the Magento root directory.

That will at least rule that out if nothing else.